# linux : sed -e expression error

Tags: linux, sed

Im trying to use sed to recursively replace mysql string, like this

```
find /var/www/html -type f -exec \
sed -i 'mysql_real_escape_string(/$conn->qStr(/g' {} +
```

the objective

```
find: mysql_real_escape_string(
replace to: $conn->qStr(
```

but it gives me error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `m'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `m'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `m'
```

any help would be great.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should supply the `s` command:

```
find /var/www/html -type f -exec \
sed -i 's/mysql_real_escape_string(/$conn->qStr(/g' {} +
```